# More than one source for a process

Tags: enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

I have a sequence diagram in Enterprise Architect.

In it is a process which can be initiated by one of two sources: either a timer process or a manual one (a user hitting a button on a GUI screen).

How do I show this on the diagram, please?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence diagram does not allow you to show two alternative invocations of the same operation. You could achieve this in an activity diagram using two different receive events leading to the same activity, but in a sequence diagram you can't draw two messages to the same sequence.

What you can do is call other sequences from within a sequence.

You do this by first drawing the sequence for the process, not showing how it is initiated or by whom but only what happens within the process.

You then draw two separate sequence diagrams for the two different cases, and into each you drag the first sequence diagram and drop it as an "Interaction Occurrence."

Finally, you draw a message from the actor to the interaction occurrence. The occurrence can be double-clicked in the diagram, which opens up the sequence diagram describing the process.

[image]

A related problem is, of course, that there is no standard way of showing spontaneous occurrences (timeouts) in sequence diagrams, since they focus on interaction between a caller and a callee (often in a cascade). The simplest way of dealing with this is to create an actor "Clock" or similar, and have it initiate the process.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to introduce an interface (or a superclass) that is common to the timer process and the manual invocation and set that as the user, as the calls (I assume) are likely to call the same basic method anyway.

If they behave quite differently, I'd go with Uffe's advice and create 2 diagrams.

Some tools also allow for using fragments in sequence diagrams ([see corresponding help text for Enterprise architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_sequencediagram.html)).
Then you may use e.g. the "alt" fragment. Note the advice in the given link, though: "sequence diagrams are not intended for showing complex procedural logic".